# Packaging Play application for windows using Native sbt Packager

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, sbt-native-packager

I have made a small HTTP serveur with play. I want now to buil a windows version with an install. I have already made one few month ago but I have modified my application so I have to remake an install. But, without changing everything in the sbt file, it fail...

Here the command I use for building the install :

```
activator windows:packageBin
```

Here the error I get when I launch the application after installation :

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:66)
        at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$$anonfun$initialConfiguration$1.apply(Application.scala:76)
        at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$$anonfun$initialConfiguration$1.apply(Application.scala:76)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.initialConfiguration(Application.scala:75)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.initialConfiguration$lzycompute(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.initialConfiguration(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalClass(Application.scala:25)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalClass$lzycompute(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalClass(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:31)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal$lzycompute(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:54)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:53)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:52)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.global(Application.scala:68)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.global(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:82)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration$lzycompute(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultConfiguration$$fullConfiguration(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.WithDefaultConfiguration$class.configuration(Application.scala:84)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.configuration(Application.scala:402)
        at play.api.Application$class.$init$(Application.scala:274)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:406)
        at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:53)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:253)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:289)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:284)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:284)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleIncluder.fromBasename(SimpleIncluder.java:235)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.parseResourcesAnySyntax(ConfigImpl.java:128)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax(ConfigFactory.java:811)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:113)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:136)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.loadDefaultConfig(ConfigFactory.java:228)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.access$000(ConfigFactory.java:38)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory$1.call(ConfigFactory.java:378)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory$1.call(ConfigFactory.java:375)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl$LoaderCache.getOrElseUpdate(ConfigImpl.java:58)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.computeCachedConfig(ConfigImpl.java:86)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:375)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(ConfigFactory.java:299)
        at play.api.Configuration$.dontAllowMissingConfig$lzycompute(Configuration.scala:29)
        at play.api.Configuration$.dontAllowMissingConfig(Configuration.scala:29)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:64)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:183)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:170)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:148)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleIncluder.fromBasename(SimpleIncluder.java:185)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:579)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:554)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:176)
        ... 52 more
```

And here my sbt file :

```
name := """IDTabDriver"""

name in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageSummary in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

packageDescription in Windows := "IdTabDriver"

maintainer in Windows := "My Company"

organization := "My Company"

version := "1.0.0.1"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.10",
  "org.rxtx" % "rxtxcomm" % "2.0-7pre1"
)
```

If any one have an idea, I have tried so much things I can't find solution

Comment: Does this happen when you build it or when you run it (after installation)? Which version of play are you using? (Do you use `play run` or `activator run` to start it locally?)

Comment: It happens at run time, so when running after the installation. I start it with the generated idtabdriver.bat file. When I run it in my dev environement (in intelliji) it works very well. I'm with Play 2.3

Comment: Can you check the java version on the server and on your local machine?

Comment: I run this application on my own machine. But I have 2 version of java (for developement purpose), who can I know wich version is in use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered the same error complaining that the resource  application.conf is not found on classpath. This might be related to a [know bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/378#issuecomment-85581556) in sbt-play plugin. Until the [recent bug fix](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4116) is released, try adding the following line to your build.sbt as a workaround as [suggested by the Play development team](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/624#issuecomment-127809288).

```
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply using what comes with Play then all you need to run is `dist` in the SBT console.

Then look in `target/universal` for a zipped file.  When you unzip run the `.bat` file in the `bin` folder.